# Can vertex connectivity of a plane graph be characterized by a special closed Jordan curve?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-connectivity

Let $P$ be a plane, and a simple closed curve $l$ on $P$ is *separating* if $P-l$ is not connected.

My question is as follows.

**Question** Let $G$  be a planar graph with connectivity $k$, and $\phi(G)$ be a plane embedding of $G$. If $ S:=\{u_1,u_2,\dots u_k\}$ is a $k$-separating set of $G$. Then $\phi(G)$ admits a simple separating closed curve $l$ on $P$ intersecting only $u_1,u_2 ,\dots,$ and $u_k$ which separates $P$ so that each component of $P-l$  contains at least one component of $G − S$.

The above question is observed from some specific examples below, in conjunction with the proof of Lemma 11 in a paper (Noguchi, K., Suzuki, Y. Relationship Among Triangulations, Quadrangulations and Optimal 1-Planar Graphs. Graphs and Combinatorics 31, 1965–1972 (2015)). But I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note: The three red dotted lines $l_i$ for $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ in the figures above represent the Jordan closed curves satisfying the conditions in the qustion, separately.

[image]

PS: Recently I have been reading some paper on planar graphs or 1-plane graphs, and I see that Jordan curves often play a key role for proving the connectivity of graphs. I wonder if there are some systematic papers or books that summarize examples of the role of Jordan curves in graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you won't get a cut that contains each point in $S$, but only a subset. For the proof, take one component $C$ of $G \setminus S$, and let $S' \subseteq S$ be the points of $S$ adjacent to some vertex in $C$. Consider the subgraph induced by $C \cup S'$: its border defines a curve, which can be slightly enlarged to be a simple closed curve intersecting $\phi(G)$ only on $S'$.

Comment: Do you mean by generality that this vertex cut $S$ may not be a minimal cut? It's true that if it's not a minimal cut, then we do choose the subset  $S'$ of $S$.  So I limit the vertex connectivity of G to $k$ so that $S$ is a minimal cut.

Comment: Yes, if it is a minimum cut, then in my answer $S' = S$, because for a minimum cut, all components are adjacent to each vertex of the minimum cut.

Comment: Interestingly, I see from your statement that all vertices of $S'$ should lie on the boundary of some face of $C∪S′$. I don't know if I'm right.